# Using JavaScript to change table cells width

Tags: javascript, html, css

My table td width in CSS is 150px.

I am thinking of using JavaScript to change the particular td width to 2px.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this (for the first one:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].style.width = '2px';
```

Or this for all:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
    tds[i].style.width = '2px';
```